# Multiple ffmpeg processes and multiple RTMP outputs

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

Debian user here.

Desperately looking not even a solution but at least a hint about how to debug this situation.

I need to run multiple ffmpeg processes simultaneously:

`ffmpeg -loglevel error -f concat -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -safe 0 -i playlist.txt -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`

`ffmpeg -loglevel error -f concat -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -safe 0 -i playlist2.txt -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy`

et cetera, different playlists, rtmp youtube outputs with different stream keys.

Currentyly if I'll start two ffmpeg processes only the first one is streaming to YouTube second one is working fine without any errors and YT even indicates that there is data coming but there is no stream.

Tried to start each ffmpeg process under different user, no luck

Don't know who to blame.

Comment: Do both processes work when run alone?

Comment: Yep, both working fine, no errors but only one stream is active. Also this is two different YT channels.

Comment: Then, not ffmpeg related. YT may only allow one active stream per IP or account - check their docs or forums.

Comment: same question on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/1033693/multiple-ffmpeg-processes-and-multiple-rtmp-outputs